# Checking if feature class locked in ArcGIS using ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.3, lock

I'm trying to find a way to determine whether a feature class is locked before trying to alter it.

In one database I want to remove a feature class completely, and in another I want to add extra fields.  I can't do either if they're locked.

I was expecting to find something in `arcpy.Describe()` but haven't found anything.  Something like

```
if arcpy.Describe(myFC).isLocked:
    print "Can't proceed - feature class is locked"
else:
    arcpy.Delete_management(myFC)
```

Is there a way to check feature class locks using arcpy?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found it - I was using incorrect terminology in my searches.

There is a tool called [Test Schema Lock](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/testschemalock.htm) which will return `True` or `False` based on whether a lock can be applied or not.  So my code would be:

```
if not arcpy.TestSchemaLock(myFC):
    print "Can't proceed - feature class is locked"
else:
    arcpy.Delete_management(myFC)
```

Because it returns `True` if the feature class isn't locked (i.e. a lock *can* be applied), an `if not` needs to be used to find where it returns `False` (it is locked).

Comment: Does this work on the entire gdb as well as individual feature classes?  What about shapefiles?

Comment: @CraigT it's only 4 lines, have you tried it?  I suspect it will work for shapefiles as well, but I haven't tried.  I don't know about entire gdb - locks are usually per feature class so I'm not sure if a gdb reports it is locked.  You could loop through each feature class to determine which is locked and which isn't

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is outdated now.

You can use arcpy.testSchemaLock() instead.

Link to Doc.
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/functions/testschemalock.htm

Comment: What syntax is outdated?  Your suggested solution is the same as the accepted answer