# Issue with editing a feature class within ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, schema-locks

I have tried editing a feature class in an ArcGIS drawing which results to an error related to the specific geodatabase. The description in the error says `"Check to see that you have the appropriate permissions"`. The same issue applies to all feature classes within the specific geodatabase.

I have double-checked that the drawing is not open on a colleagues machine, in order to avoid any Schema Lock related issues. Furthermore, other colleagues are experiencing the same issue with the specific drawing, so it is not something happening only on my end.

While I cannot edit any feature class within the geodatabase, I can delete them.

Does anybody knows what might be the issue here?

Comment: Do you have read/write permission set in Windows? Is this a local geodatabase or one on a shared drive?

Comment: Yes I have, since I am able to make changes in all other drawings. The geodatabase in on a shared drive.

Comment: I have had this situation arises when working on a shared drive. Usually, there is some sort of lock from one of the users. Try restarting ArcGIS on all of the local computers that may be accessing the geodatabase to see if the lock clears. You can test for a lock too using arcpy: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/202482/8104